# Adding foreach into a db query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display all the categories and the count but I can only get one at a time.

```
$query = $db->write_query('
    SELECT c.*, COUNT(n.id) AS count
    FROM ' . TABLE_PREFIX . 'newscategories c
    LEFT JOIN ' . TABLE_PREFIX . 'news n ON FIND_IN_SET (c.cid, n.cid)
    GROUP BY c.cid
    ORDER BY count DESC
    ');    

while($fetch = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    $name = $fetch['name'];
    $count = $fetch['count'];
}



echo $name;
```

This only prints one. Trying to get all of them to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can echo the name inside the loop as the others suggested

```
while($fetch = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    $name = $fetch['name'];
    $count = $fetch['count'];
    echo $name . " " . $count ."<br />";

}
```

or save your returned data in an array, and then loop through the array

```
$results = array()
while($fetch = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    $results[] = array( 'name' => $fetch['name'],
                        'count' => $fetch['count']);
}

foreach ($results as $result){    
     echo $result['name']. " " . $result['count'] ."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. What if I want to execute some more code after it echos 10? Like I want to list 10 categories, then put the rest in a div that I can use jQuery to hide or show.

Comment: Use a counter, and once it reaches 11, then add the opening div tag. and after the loop, check to see if it is over 10 and add the closing tag -> `$i=1; foreach ($results as $result){ if($i==11){ echo '<div class="hideMe">'; } echo $result['name']. " " . $result['count'] ."<br />"; $i++; } if($i>10) {echo '</div>';}`

Answer (score 0):

Print inside the loop.

```
while($fetch = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    $name = $fetch['name'];
    $count = $fetch['count'];

    echo "$name: $count\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only ever `echo` one value:

```
echo $name;
```

Each time your loop runs, it overwrites that variable, so you'll only ever print the last value.  It sounds like you want to print the value inside the loop itself:

```
while($fetch = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    $name = $fetch['name'];
    $count = $fetch['count'];
    echo $name;
}
```

(Note: From this starting point you'll likely want to improve the output formatting, reduce unnecessary code, etc.)